# MSAccess Binding a Pulldown combobox to a sub-form

Tags: forms, ms-access, data-binding, subquery, ms-access-2010

I have a multi-column pulldown combo box (cmb_users) that lists user names on a form (frm_myusers), the data is straight from a table called "dbo.my_users", primary key "pc_user_id", and it is the first column in the pulldown.

I then have a multi-form sub-form embedded into the parent form (frm_myusers) that contain one or more roles for each user. The data source is straight from a table called "dbo.my_users_roles" its primary key is pc_user_id. The relationship between dbo.my_users and dbo.my_users_roles is 1 to many.

[image]

The challenge I am having is When I try to bind the combobox to the sub-form I get the "cannot bind to an unbound form error"

[image]

So then I tried passing the combobox values to a query (qry_my_users_roles)behind the scenes to drive the sub-form. The criteria for the query was on pc_user_id as **=[Forms]![frm_users]!cmb_users.Column(0)**, and I get the error below. Not sure where to go from here.

[image]

Ultimately is there a way to simply bind a pulldown to a sub-form without the need to jump through hoops passing variables to queries and refreshing? Mapping fields to query criteria can be quite cumbersome of the spelling or syntax is not absolutely perfect :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usual approach is to use subform container master/child links properties to link on PK and FK fields, not controls. If purpose of combobox is to enter filter criteria then it should be UNBOUND and use some code to either apply filter to main form or go to record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the combobox is unbound, add it to the master fields:

```
sci_cnt_id;NameOfCombobox
```

and adjust the child fields as well:

```
sci_cnt_id;sci_own_id
```

Should you wish to show all records, you must maintain the field count, so use:

```
sci_cnt_id;sci_cnt_id
```

Comment: The sci_cnt_id is the internal sql uid.. what I want to bind on is sc_owner_id.. That said, I tried sc_owner_id;cmb_users for the master, and the child as sc_owner_id and it return that expression typo error. Jun7 made a point.. since the pulldown is both pulldown and filter I will have to throw some code at it. Too bad pulldowns dont work like the typical form object otherwise it would save on code. I will still give you credit for the suggestion - it will be useful for a different scenario